# Problem with defining a titlepage

Tags: errors, titles, documentclass-writing

I am writing a LaTeX 2e class with two options `msc` and `phd` for my department theses/dissertations. In this class, I need to define a titlepage for the first page of the theses/dissertations which contains the university name, the department name, the title, the author name and so on. The code is something like the following:

```
\documentclass[‎phd‎]{‎book‎}‎
‎\makeatletter‎‎
‎‎\newif\if@‎phdthesis‎
‎\@‎phdthesis‎‎false‎
‎\DeclareOption{phd}{\@‎phdthesis‎‎true}‎
‎\newif\if@‎msc‎thesis‎‎
‎\@‎mscthesis‎‎false‎
‎\DeclareOption{‎msc‎}{\@‎mscthesis‎‎true}‎‎
‎‎‎
‎\def\author‎#1{\gdef\@‎author‎{#1}}‎‎‎‎
‎‎\if@‎mscthesis‎‎
‎\def‎‎\mytitle‎‎{‎‎‎‎‎\begin{titlepage}‎‎‎‎
    \begin{center}‎
    ‎A‎  thesis ‎for the degree ‎of master of science by‎\\‎
    ‎\@author‎‎
    \end{center}‎‎
    ‎\end‎{titlepage}‎‎‎‎
‎‎‎‎}‎‎
‎\fi‎
‎‎\if@‎phdthesis‎‎
‎\def‎‎‎\my‎title{‎‎‎‎\begin{titlepage}‎‎‎
‎   \begin{center}‎
    A ‎Dissertation‎ for the ‎Degree‎‎ of Doctor of ‎Philosophy ‎by\\‎
    \@author‎
‎   \end{center}‎‎‎‎
    ‎\end‎{titlepage}‎‎
‎‎‎‎}‎‎
‎\fi‎
‎\makeato‎ther‎
\begin{document}‎
\author{‎Vahid‎}‎‎‎
‎‎\mytitle‎
‎‎\chapter{Chapter Name}‎
‎bla ‎bla ‎bla‎
‎\newpage‎
‎bla ‎bla ‎bla‎‎
‎\end{document}
```

But I get an error: `Undefined control sequence.l.32 \mytitle`. I am wondering if anybody help me solve this problem.

Comment: There are some funny invisible zero-width (spaces?) unicode characters in your code post. They are displayed as `<200e>` in Vim and make it uncompilable for me.

Comment: @Martin: I'm sorry for that. I'm using Texmaker which has been modified for typesetting Right to left languages for writing my code.

Comment: Consider the `memoir` class if your university (like mine) has very odd formatting requirements. Chapter 21 of the memoir documentation is an example of doing a thesis design. You can piece enough together with the `titlesec`, `tocloft`, and other related packages, but memoir provides most/all of their functionality in one class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this error, because you define the two versions of `\mytitle` inside conditionals. Both of them are false in you example, so the macro never gets defined.

You missing an `\ProcessOptions` which actually handles the given `[phd]` option, *before* the first use of the `if`'s:

```
%...
‎\DeclareOption{‎msc‎}{\@‎mscthesis‎‎true}‎‎
\ProcessOptions   

‎\def\author‎#1{\gdef\@‎author‎{#1}}‎‎‎‎
%...
```

I assume here the code is in a class file.
Please also see the `clsguide` for more information on how to define options.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. But I cannot exactly understand what you mean. Could you please help me to avoid the error?

Comment: @Vahid: see the update

Answer (score 3):

use it this way, which use msc as default:

```
\documentclass[‎phd]{book}
\makeatletter

\newif\if@phdthesis
‎\DeclareOption{‎phd‎}{\@‎phdthesis‎‎true}‎‎
\ProcessOptions
‎‎‎
‎\def‎‎‎\my‎title{‎‎‎‎\begin{titlepage}‎‎‎
‎   \begin{center}‎
   ‎‎\if@‎phdthesis‎‎
      A ‎Dissertation‎ for the ‎Degree‎‎ of Doctor of ‎Philosophy ‎by\par
   \else‎
      ‎A‎  thesis ‎for the degree ‎of master of science by‎\par
   \fi
    \@author‎
‎   \end{center}‎‎‎‎
‎\end‎{titlepage}‎‎}‎‎
‎
‎\makeato‎ther‎
\begin{document}
\author{‎Vahid‎}‎‎‎
‎‎\mytitle‎
‎‎\chapter{Chapter Name}‎
‎bla ‎bla ‎bla‎
‎\newpage‎
‎bla ‎bla ‎bla‎‎
‎\end{document}
```